# What kind of word is "Оттого"?

Tags: грамматика

Adverb? Preposition? Particle/Delimiter? Is there a recommended book where I can look up such questions? I couldn't find it in the New Penguin Russian Course book.

Answer (score 1):

It can play a role of either [adverb (наречие)](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE) - in most of the cases - or, sometimes, conjunction ("союз") pretty much like it counterparts ["поэтому"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83), ["потому"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83) etc.
You can find this information in any decent Russian dictionary.

Sometimes this kind of adverbs are called ["местоименные наречия"](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B5) - as opposed to so-called ["знаменательные наречия"](https://russky.info/ru/grammar/adverbs).

Answer (score 0):

It is an indicative pronoun (указательное местоимение), similar to это, то, того... "Оттого, что..." is a conjunction (союз).